# How do I plot contour plot for the given data

Tags: r

How do I plot a contour for this data set?

```
                         phi                    
n     0.0        0.1        0.2     0.3      0.4    0.5     0.6     0.7     0.8      0.9
100   0.5772    0.5762  0.5757  0.5752  0.5748  0.5742  0.5737  0.5716  0.5656  0.5594
300   0.5769    0.5761  0.5754  0.5747  0.5736  0.5728  0.5718  0.5682  0.565   0.5492
500   0.5763    0.5755  0.5748  0.5746  0.5732  0.572   0.5713  0.5674  0.5606  0.5449
1000  0.5755    0.5752  0.5742  0.5739  0.5723  0.5709  0.5689  0.5658  0.559   0.5422
3000  0.5753    0.5747  0.574   0.5737  0.5719  0.5707  0.5687  0.5652  0.5575  0.5419
5000  0.5749    0.5743  0.5738  0.5734  0.5714  0.5698  0.5679  0.5646  0.5566  0.5401
```

0.0, 0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9 are the phi values

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `contour()` function. You need to organize your data so that you have numeric vectors `n` and `p1` and a numeric matrix `x` (depending on how you have your data stored, use indexing with `[` to select appropriate rows and columns, and possibly `as.matrix()` to convert from a data frame to a matrix.

```
summary(n)
##    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
##     100     350     750    1650    2500    5000 
summary(p1)
##   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
##  0.000   0.225   0.450   0.450   0.675   0.900
summary(x)
## num [1:6, 1:10] 0.577 0.577 0.576 0.576 0.575 ...
## - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
##  ..$ : NULL
##  ..$ : NULL
```

Then all you need is:

```
contour(n,p1,x)
```

See `?contour` for more details.